# Why is a destructor directly after calling an implicit type conversion constructor?

Tags: c++, gcc, implicit-conversion

Give the following function:

```
osal_allocator* SharedMemoryManager::allocator();I
```

Where `osal_allocator` is a 'c' structure, containing function pointers.

And the a wrapper class that provides the following constructor:

```
Allocator::Allocator( osal_allocator* );
```

A function makes the following call:

```
001 SomeFunc( SharedMemoryManager* shm )
002 {
003    Allocator myAllocator = shm.allocator();
004
005    myAllocator.doSomething();
006
007    // stuff
008 }
```

The code fails with a `SIG SEGV`.  The reason is that on line `003` the destructor for `myAllocator` is called immediately after its constructor is called. This means that `myAllocator` is invalid on line `005`, since it has been destroyed.

(Note: the default constructor is not being called and neither are any assignment operators).

If line `003` is changed to:

```
003    Allocator myAllocator( shm.allocator );
```

The function works as expected, with `myAllocators`'s destructor not being called until it goes out of scope.

Unfortunately I have not been able to reproduce this issue with a simple example.

I am using :

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
```

With the following options:

```
c++ -MD -D__LINUX__  -g -ansi -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wno-format-security -Woverloaded-virtual -Iinc
```

**Why is the compiler generating a destructor call for the first example**

Comment: The answer to your problems is, You need to properly & correctly follow the **Rule of Three**.

Comment: Please post the *actual, minimal complete code* and not just some approximation. Your code won’t compile.

Comment: "Why is the compiler generating invalid code for the first example" chances are areally high, that it isn't.

Comment: Your right - I instinctively followed the "rule of 3" in my attempt to reproduce the error - unfortunately the code I was calling doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line

```
Allocator myAllocator = shm.allocator();
```

You are doing the following operations:

1. Construct a new `Allocator` temporary object
2. Call the copy constructor of `Allocator` where the rhs is the temporary
3. Destroy the temporary object created at point 1

There are two possible operations which you din't consider and that may cause the SIG SEV: copy constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 1):

`Allocator myAllocator = shm.allocator();` is copy initialization and involves the call of a conversion constructor (from a `osal_allocator*`) and a copy constructor (from the temporary `Allocator`). The destructor that's being called is that of the temporary `Allocator` object.

The crash is probably due to a missing copy constructor, or poorly implemented copy constructor in `Allocator`.

This is backed up by your claim that changing the initialization to

```
Allocator myAllocator( shm.allocator );
```

works - this is because there's no copy involved - the conversion constructor is called directly, no temporary object is created.

[Read up on "the rule of three".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Basically, if a class requires either of a destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator (which is usually the case when a class manages resources), it requires **all three of them**.

Comment: Ruke of Three - That is why my attempt to reproduce the issue works and the real code doesn't - it follows the rule of 3 but the code (not mine) for Allocator is missing a copy constructor....